# Below is the input and output, along with a code snippet of what i've done. Can we write a function to take ids dynamically and create the output?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

***Input***

```
{"records" : {
    "a1s1X000000YKalQAG" : {
      "apiName" : "SP_Attribute__c",
      "childRelationships" : { },
      "eTag" : "c9439586feca3af5df2121fe7cfbc4ca",
      "fields" : {
        "Name" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "EuipmentRecord2"
        },
        "SP_Internal_Number__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "a"
        },
        "SP_Type__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "B"
        },
        "SP_Unit__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "C"
        },
        "SP_Value__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "D"
        }
      },
      "id" : "a1s1X000000YKalQAG",
      "lastModifiedById" : "0051X0000090wZKQAY",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2021-11-19T10:18:57.000Z",
      "recordTypeId" : "012000000000000AAA",
      "recordTypeInfo" : null,
      "systemModstamp" : "2021-11-19T10:18:57.000Z",
      "weakEtag" : 1637317137000
    },
    "a1s1X000000YIWLQA4" : {
      "apiName" : "SP_Attribute__c",
      "childRelationships" : { },
      "eTag" : "fd1b7751ece0fee39101ca1e0bbb80b3",
      "fields" : {
        "Name" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "EuipmentRecord1"
        },
        "SP_Internal_Number__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "SP_Type__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "SP_Unit__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "SP_Value__c" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        }
      },
      "id" : "a1s1X000000YIWLQA4",
      "lastModifiedById" : "0051X0000090wZKQAY",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2021-11-09T12:36:22.000Z",
      "recordTypeId" : "012000000000000AAA",
      "recordTypeInfo" : null,
      "systemModstamp" : "2021-11-09T12:36:22.000Z",
      "weakEtag" : 1636461382000
    }
  }}
```

***Dataweave***

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var ids = ["a1s1X000000YKalQAG", "a1s1X000000YIWLQA4"]
var a = [payload.records."$(ids[0])".fields pluck (($$): $.value)]++ [(payload.records."$(ids[1])".fields pluck (($$): $.value))]
---
a
```

***Output***

```
[
  [
    {
      "Name": "EuipmentRecord2"
    },
    {
      "SP_Internal_Number__c": "a"
    },
    {
      "SP_Type__c": "B"
    },
    {
      "SP_Unit__c": "C"
    },
    {
      "SP_Value__c": "D"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Name": "EuipmentRecord1"
    },
    {
      "SP_Internal_Number__c": null
    },
    {
      "SP_Type__c": null
    },
    {
      "SP_Unit__c": null
    },
    {
      "SP_Value__c": null
    }
  ]
]
```

Keeping the output same, the challenge is to write a function which dynamically takes these ids and creates the output, so in this example there are two ids - "a1s1X000000YKalQAG", "a1s1X000000YIWLQA4", so the variable "a" had two arrays to be concatenated, [payload.records."$(ids[0])".fields pluck (($$): $.value)]++ [(payload.records."$(ids[1])".fields pluck (($$): $.value))].

Can we write a function to make the whole thing dynamic? so if there are n ids, -> id1 ++ id2 ++ id3... id(n) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs seem to be the keys of the records value, so you can just use the [namesOf()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-namesof) function to extract the keys as a list of strings to avoid have it hardcoded in the script:

```js
%dw 2.0 
output application/json
fun convertById(data) = 
    payload.records 
        pluck ($.fields)
        map ($ pluck (($$): $.value) )
---
convertById(payload)
```

Update: encapsulated it into a function.
Update2: make it dynamical for any number of ids.

Comment: Yes but I want to have a function which creates the var a dynamically, let's say there are 4 IDs, so var a =  payload.records.ID1.fields  ++ payload.records.ID2.fields ++ payload.ID3.fields ++ payload.ID4.fields,                                                     
 if there is 1 ID payload.records.ID1.fields.                         If there are 2 IDs payload.records.ID1.fields ++ payload.records.ID2.fields.

Comment: I encapsulated the logic into a function. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: The number of IDs are to be taken as the number of
Concatenations for variable a. The logic which we have write now for creating "var a" will only work for two Ids, I want it to work for as many ids there are in var ids

Comment: Example:
`var Ids = ["Id1", "Id2", "Id3", "Id4",......."Id(n)"]

var a = [payload.records.Id1.fields] ++ [payload.records.Id2.fields] ++ [payload.records.Id3.fields] ++ ...... ++ [payload.records.Id(n)]`

Comment: I see I missed that part. Let me review it.

Comment: Fixed now. It is smaller, though not as obvious maybe.

Comment: Thanks man! it works, you the best :D